# How to prove the consistency of aggregates in DDD (Technically)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, consistency, aggregateroot

Ensuring the consistency of our aggregate is so important thing when developing web applications using DDD.

I worked in the past on a web application(no DDD) where we tried to ensure the consistency of our data using Transactions.So, We used Serializable transaction level and it was a nightmare for our team because the performance of our application was so bad and a lot of deadlocks issues have been reported by our users.

Now I am working on a web application implementing DDD principles and I need to ensure the consistency of our aggregates.

I have read here http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/04/07/152643.aspx that optimistic concurrency/locking is one of the methods to achieve that throw assigning a version or timestamp to our aggregate to check against it.

My first question is how to achieve optimistic concurrency using C# and entity framework in conjunction with Sql Server including the whole process from the beginning to the end, and where to store that column/flag if we take order and line items example which Eric Evans gave it in his book?

My second question is what are the common strategies used to ensure aggregates consistency in case of race conditions?

I would appreciate any code snippet or references.

Comment: I've been working on a conceptual design for the same problem recently. I am planning to have a global version counter which increments on every database write. And also to add a version column to all tables which records the current version counter at the time of the row creation/modification. Every modification to a row has to specify what version of the row to modify and fail the transaction when the version doesn't match.

Comment: @XiaoguoGe in optimistic locking you don't use transactions

Comment: you can still use translations but without locking.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is how to achieve optimistic concurrency using C# and entity framework in conjunction with Sql Server including the whole process from the beginning to the end, and where to store that column/flag if we take order and line items example which Eric Evans gave it in his book?

If you use a single table to store the entire Aggregate then you can use optimistic locking. For example you could use a [JSON column to store](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=942) the line items. For this case the document base NoSQL databases are a perfect fit.

If you use multiple tables (i.e. one table for the order and one table for the line-items) then I don't see how you could *reliably* use optimistic locking to ensure atomicity. In this case you need transactions.

> My second question is what are the common strategies used to ensure aggregates consistency in case of race conditions?

You just [retry the command](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es/blob/master/src/Gica/Cqrs/Command/CommandDispatcher/ConcurrentProofFunctionCaller.php). If you designed your Aggregate to be side effect free (at least to not make any IO calls) then this should not be a problem.

Comment: but in case of multiple tables using Serializable transaction level it was a nightmare.For this purpose what do you think the best transaction level should I use to prevent deadlocks and preventing updating outdated aggregates.

Comment: @SimpleCode if you have a rich domain I recommend to change the architecture to CQRS and Event sourcing

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu As far as I can tell a READ COMMITTED transaction with optimistic locking on one table should be enough to detect concurrency conflicts, even if the AR's data is scattered among multiple tables. The UPDLOCK will be held for the entire duration of the transaction so the version check would work across transactions.

Comment: @plalx I would upvote your comment.I think this would work perfectly with less efforts to maintain that, cause in my situation I don't need to implement CQRS/ES as this complexity it's not justified in my project.

Comment: @plalx You are right however optimistic locking is not pessimistic locking (doh!); "question is how to achieve optimistic concurrency using C# and entity framework" - if one is using transactions (at any level) then it is not optimistic locking;

Comment: @plalx one thing to note is that read committed transaction solves the concurrent write problem. But it can not solve the stale write problem. An aggregate can still overwrite records with out dated data.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu In most relational DB there's always an implicit database transaction whether you explicitly start one or not. Also even if you modify a single table in your transaction there is still an exclusive lock that is held when performing the write. You can't escape some level of serialization.

Comment: @XiaoguoGe That is why you also need an `expectedVersion` from the client issuing the command.

Comment: @plalx I won't agree on this. That "default  transaction" is not a transaction at all. A transaction can be rolled back, that can't. Locking (table or row level) and transaction is not the same.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Perhaps, but the end result is the same. You can't have optimistic locking without write locks (serialization). Therefore, if you defer all you writes to the end of your transactions you should have the minimum amount of serialization required, which is much different from making the entire process serialized from the start.